# The figurative use of the word "barrage"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, connotation, figures-of-speech

The word "barrage" means a concentrated artillery bombardment. But it is also used figuratively  for when someone is being hit with a lot of questions or criticism. The word shares this with the word "bombardment", as in; "a bombardment of questions" - "a barrage of questions".

My understanding of the word had always been that its scope is wider than just for questions and criticism. I believed that it could be used to name any big bunch of anything. As in, "a barrage of guards running after him". So, my questions are:

Can it be used this way?

And

If so, is it connotatively off to use it so?

Comment: You are bombarded by a barrage of questions. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No I'm afraid not, how does it relate to my question?

Comment: We generally do not say: a bombardment of questions. In any case, since a barrage means: concentrated military bombardment, it follows that "a barrage of guards" would not work. However, **a barrage of guards poured out of the fort** might work. Then, the guards are metaphorically like a bombardment.

Comment: You can use the metaphor as you like; keep in mind it has the idea of something directed against you; that’s what it brings to mind for the reader.

Comment: I could see, eg, "a barrage of errors" or even "a barrage of Valentine cards" -- basically anything arriving suddenly, en masse.

Comment: If you have never needed to hug the ground and dig in during a  real "barrage", the meaning might escape you.

Answer (score 1):

**barrage**  n.

Literally, a barrage is a bombardment (concentrated discharge) of artillery fire, bullets etc.

Figuratively the word ...  [Columbia Guide to Standard American English](https://books.google.com/books?id=l9g3BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA56&ots=488TpEXp-n&dq=figurative%20use%20of%20barrage&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q=figurative%20use%20of%20barrage&f=false)

> is also used to signify an overwhelming quantity or outpouring of
>   **anything**. In her I962 book *Silent Spring* (R Carson) said of America's widespread use of chemical insecticide: "As crude a weapon
>   as a caveman's club, the chemical barrage has been hurled against the
>   fabric of life."

Parsing your question to the use of barrage, **a barrage of pursuing guards** is grammatical, at least in AmE. A quick search reveals a barrage of pain, a barrage of rain and yes even a barrage of valentine cards! Andbthere are many more barrages of X.